# For the $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ find idempotents matrix $E_1,E_2.E_3$ so that $A=x_1E_1+x_2E_2+x_3E_3$ .

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -14 & -10 \\ -14 & -2 & -4 \\ -10 & -4 & 10 \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$ and idempotents matrix $E_1,E_2.E_3$ so that $A=x_1E_1+x_2E_2+x_3E_3$.

The matrix $A$ have eigenvalues $x_1=9$, $x_2=-18$ and $x_3=18$.

I don't have idea of how build the idempotents matrix $E_1,E_2.E_3$. I wait that you can give me a hints or say me the theorem for find this idempotents matrix.

Comment: Hint: An idempotent matrix represents a projection. Think about the action of $A$ on each of its eigenspaces.

Answer (score 0):

For each eigenvalue, find an eigenvector, call it $w,$ as a column vector. Next, define column vector  $v = w /|w|,$ which is now a unit length vector. You should confirm unit length.

Now, if you write $v^T v$ you just get the one by one matrix with single entry $1;$ usually people just say $v^T v = 1.$

Instead, the idempotent matrix for that eigenvalue is
$$  E = v v^T  $$ 
This is a symmetric matrix of rank one, positive semi-definite but not definite. It has trace exactly $1.$ Finally,
$E^2 = v v^T v v^T = v (v^T v) v^T = v (1) v^T = v  v^T = E$

Comment: ..is not true that $A=x_1E_1+x_2E_2+x_3E_3$.

Comment: @LuisPrado actually, it works perfectly, and the numbers are not bad at all. Everything comes out rational. If you want further help, edit in the eigenvectors to your question, and edit in the matrix $E_1$ that results for the eigenvalue $9$

Comment: Orthogonal projection works for this matrix because the eigenspaces of the symmetric matrix are orthogonal, but it doesn’t for a general diagonalizable matrix because it might not annihilate the other eigenspaces are required.

Comment: @amd I know. My answer used symmetry and distinct eigenvalues. My concern at this point is getting the OP to carry this out. I have seen no sign that he has ever found an eigenvector of any matrix; look at his other questions and comments.

Comment: Yeah. At any rate, my comment wasn’t intended to point out an error, but as a footnote to future readers.